# Term for the CoeXisT-like images?

Tags: logo, typography, style-identification, terminology

Is there a term in design for the logos that mix images/symbols the same way the [Coexist logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coexist_(image)) does?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely certain there's a standard term.

I tend to use [Symbology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbology_(disambiguation)) or [Symbolic System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language).

> .... a set of strings of symbols together with a set of rules that are specific to it.

It's a use of symbols in a specific manner as opposed to an "alphabet" which uses formal symbols.

But again, I'm not stating this is a standard, recognized, definition by everyone.